# Does startup disk creator work with windows iso's

Tags: boot, usb

So ive created a usb disk for Ubuntu many times but i now want to install windows on my gaming rig. I went through the same process  (creating ubuntu boot disk) and its fine but when i do it with the windows iso it failed on me, im trying again now but any help woukd be great

Comment: No, it doesn't - see [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)

Answer (score 4):

### Nopes it doesnt :(

Startup disk creator knows how to write ubuntu based isos because of the way the operating system is structured.
Windows and OSX have different file structure.
The tool that i would advise to use is
*http://en.congelli.eu/prog_info_winusb.html*

Comment: Just don't forget to click the arrow to show that the answer was useful. And no problem :) Glad i was able to help

Comment: I cant quite get winusb to install is there any alternatives? Also as im new it counts it but doesnt make it visable

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight & sudo apt-get update &  
sudo apt-get install winusb